# Is there an API available to start K6 test run or any alternate such as curl if I want to start K6 test run on a remote windows server?

Tags: performance-testing, k6

In a remote server is there an option or way to start the K6 process / load test using an API or curl command.

Example: I would like to start the k6 load test in machine 2 from machine 1

Answer (score 0):

You can run a Bash script on the remote windows server using SSH. The bash script would contain the *k6 run* command.

Running Bash script on remote windows server:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120898/running-bash-script-on-a-remote-windows-machine